# Does HP's iLO support SNMP polling?

Tags: hp, snmp, ilo

I use Nagios for monitoring my servers and network hardware.  Can I poll hardware stats (temp, fan speed, etc) via the iLO 2 management port?  How about iLO 100i via the dedicated management port option?

I'm considering HP servers, and would like to monitor them via SNMP without involving a server OS.

Comment: Hi @Boden, I am looking something similar to monitor HP servers via SNMP, did you find any solution to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this information via IPMI via iLO for most ProLiants but I think that iLO itself only provides SNMP information about itself (interface stats, power state, ip-address, link speed etc) and not detailed data such as power draw\temps\fan speeds from the SM\PM bus. All references that I can find require that the OS is running and a software management agent is installed.

Nagios supports IPMI though AFAIK so you can get it that way provided the server allows it - if I remember correctly the low end 1xx series ProLiants do not provide this level of out of band management (there is a similar restriction on Dell's 1xx Series too just in case you are checking them out).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

[HP ProLiant Onboard Administrator/Integrated Lights-Out 2 overview](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12362_na/12362_na.html):

> **Alert Administration:** HP ProLiant Onboard Administrator/Integrated Lights-Out 2 support delivery of SNMP server agent alerts as well as internally generated management processor alerts (e.g. unsuccessful login attempt), to a management console such as HP Systems Insight Manager. Traps forwarded by the processor can be configured in Insight Manager for delivery to an administrator's pager or e-mail.
>
> **Flexible Network Connectivity:**
>
> - Dedicated connection - Access HP ProLiant OA/ iLO 2 via an embedded 10/100 MB dedicated Ethernet NIC dedicated to. This enables remote management over a dedicated, out-of-band management network. In-band SNMP notification of server problems on a real-time basis is also supported without separate telephone connections or modem sharing devices. The dedicated NIC can auto-select speeds between 10 Mbps and 100 Mbps.

Comment: The question was about polling, not traps.

Comment: Yeah.  I might assume that polling is available if traps are, but the overviews I've read don't say anything about it specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I'm using a Nagios check file named [check_ilo2_health.pl](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/HP-%28Compaq%29/check_ilo2_health/details).

Comment: Interesting.  It doesn't say how it gathers information (IPMI, SNMP, other)....I'm also confused about the output of that plugin.  Is it possible to monitor specific component statistics such that I can track them over time (RRD)?

Comment: I've just poked about in that module and it appears to use an XML interface to query the iLO - pretty neat. It definitely reports temperatures, fan speeds, PSU data, critical alert status and some undefined "perfdata" but I can't tell what that means precisely.

Comment: I'm only using that plug-in for ILO health checks at this stage. I am planing to go further but it's a low priority right now. I'd suggest following the link and checking the docs. There might also be more information and/or ILO plug-in on Nagios Exchange.